# Pass form field values to partial using Rails and Cocoon

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cocoon-gem

I'm using Rails 5 with Cocoon 1.2.9. I'm trying to create a form that has a single row of input fields and a single add button. When the "add" button is clicked and the related item is created, the new item is dynamically added to a table. [image: Dynamic Table]

I thought I could pass the values through Cocoons render options on `link_to_add_association`, but I haven't been able to grab the field values and convert them to locals to pass to the partial. Is it even possible?

I've also tried capturing the values in JavaScript using `cocoon:before-insert`, but again I'm unsure how to pass the captured field values to something cocoon can use.

Is what I'm asking for possible with jQuery/cocoon or is there a better solution?

Here is my attempt to capture the input values from the static form elements before-insert, but, if it's possible, how do I pass them to cocoon for the actual insert?

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#order-items').on 'cocoon:before-insert', ->
    # This should capture the form field values...
    v_area = $('#order_v_area').val()
    v_product = $('#order_v_product').val()
    v_quantity = $('#order_v_quantity').val()
    v_comment = $('#order_v_comment').val()
    return
  return
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to set ruby variables (`v_area`, `v_product` ...?). The partial is rendered server side, in the callback you get the rendered HTML which you can then manipulate (before or after insert). Is that clearer?

Comment: Thanks for the response @nathanvda.What I am ultimately trying to do is use cocoon with a single line entry form with an add button. When the user clicks "add" the new element is added to the database and displayed in a table. I was trying to capture the variables using cocoon:before-insert but I'm unsure how to pass the captured variables to cocoon. Maybe there is a better way?